# Get HTTPOnly Cookie on iOS device

Tags: ios, cookies, browser, setcookie

Is there a way/browser for iOS to get a cookie, that is HttpOnly? I know its not accessible through JavaScript. But is there a way to read it through a plugin (e. g. Edit this cookie for Firefox)?
Or maybe there is an alternative browser app for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found an app called HTTP Catcher. It provides a local web proxy on the device itself, that captures all internet traffic. The http requests include all cookie information and meta fields.